# How do I replace a value on a specific place of a matrix?

Tags: c#, matrix

I have the following code:

```
int[,]asientos = new int[Filas,Columnas];


for (int i = 0; i < Filas; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Columnas; j++)
    {
        asientos[i, j] = -1;
    }
}
```

And i want to replace the -1 for a 0 but just in a specific position of the matrix.

For example in position (20,20) value=0.

edit: I was able to complete the matrix, but the problem now is that i need to load the value of the position from another class and we don't now how.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Filas; i++)
         {

            for (int j = 0; j < Columnas; j++)
            {
                if (Fila != 0 && Columna != 0)
                {
                    asientos[Fila-1, Columna-1] = 0;
                }
                else
                asientos[i, j] = -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you know the index, then refer to it directly: `asientos[20, 20] = 0` . Or is that not the issue? Perhaps you could clarify, if you need more info.

Comment: `if( i == 19 && j == 19) { asientos [i, j] = 0 }`

Comment: Do you know what an [`if statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) is? If so, you should be able to come up with a condition that satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Check the indices using `if` statement, like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Filas; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < Columnas; j++)
    {
        if ((i == 20) && (j == 20))
            asientos[i, j] = 0; // do it for [20,20]
        else
            asientos[i, j] = -1; // do it for all other indices
    }
}
```

Remember that arrays are indexed starting from 0, so you should exactly know, if you want 20-th element (so, with indice 19), or element with indice 20 (so, 21-th element).